# Pandigital Doubling

Tags: code-golf, math, number, integer

*Inspired by [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39979766#39979766) CMC*

Given a positive integer greater than 0, perform the following operation on it:

- If all ten single digits (`1234567890`) are in the number at least once, output the count and exit the program
- Otherwise, double the number and repeat, incrementing the count.

The count starts at 0 and is the number of times the input was doubled. For example, if the input were 617283945, it would need to be doubled once because 1234567890 has all 10 digits in it.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins. Input may be taken as a string, if you want.

### Test cases

```
input => output

617283945 => 1
2 => 67
66833 => 44
1234567890 => 0
100 => 51
42 => 55
```

Comment: Can we take input as a string?

Comment: @Stephen you may take input as a string.

Comment: @Shaggy what do you think they should be? Also, its `66833` with 2 `3`s

Comment: @Shaggy It might be that test case 2 will need a big integer since doubling 2 67 times gives 2^68

Comment: @Shaggy as with all challenges, no.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that for any `n` there exists some `k` such that `nk` is pandigital? I'd love to see a proof.

Comment: @shooqie That question was asked in the Maths chat room, but wasn't answered. I think that every `n` greater than 0 can be doubled into pandigitality. (Is that the right word?)

Comment: I checked all inputs up to 100,000 and the largest value for `n` was 78 given an input of `1471`. There may be a larger `n` for long numbers but my stupid VBA solution takes about 8 seconds per 1,000 inputs and I don't want to wait that long. I *did* find an interesting pattern, though. For the first 100,000 inputs, the number of times a certain `n` occurred fits a [normal distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMW4T.png).

Comment: What does "CMC" mean?

Comment: @bfontaine Chat Mini Challenge

Comment: @shooqie Proof! For any n which is coprime to 10, it's also coprime to 10^10, and so there exists some k such that nk is 1 mod 10^10. Then 1234567890*nk = 1234567890 mod 10^10, so each digit necessarily appears at least once.  If not, multiply by 2, 5, or 25 as necessary to make the last non-zero digit coprime with 10, and a variant of the above proof works (formally, n = 10^m * p, where p satisfies the above condition, then 1234567890\*p\*k as above is pandigital, so 1234567890\*p\*k*10^m = 1234567890*k*n is). :)

Comment: A similar idea of modular inverses proves this nicely if the question asked about tripling instead, doubling only seems a little harder.

Comment: @EngineerToast 1471 stays the largest up to 1 000 000, and is in fact the _last_ value for which the output reaches 78 below a million.

Comment: @B.Mehta Both are true up to at least `160 868 750`, too.

Comment: There's no result higher than 78 in the first 1,000,000,000 values - is there a mathematician who can tell us whether any larger results can be proved or disproved?

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 39 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:len({*str(n)})<10and-~f(n*2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qJzVPo1qruKRII0@zVtPG0CAxL0W3Lk0jT8tI839BUWZeiUaahpmhuZGFsaWJqaYmF0zMCIltZmZhbIzENzQyNjE1M7ewNEAWNEDmmQD1/wcA)

Outputs `False` for `0`.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [scottinet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73296/scottinet)

```
[D9ÝåË#·]N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/2sXy8NzDSw93Kx/aHuv3/7@ZmYWxMQA) or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVvk/2sXy8NzDSw93Kx/aHuv3v1Lp8H4rBSV7nf@GRsYmpmbmFpYGXGaG5kYWxpYmplxmZhbGxgpcRlyGBgZcJkYA)

```
[          // Start infinity loop
 D         // Duplicate current value (or input)
  9Ý       // Push [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    å      // Does each exist in the current value
     Ë#    // Break if all equal (if every digit exists)
       ·   // Else double the current value
        ]N // End loop and print the number of times through the loop
```

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/2sXy8NzDSw93Kx/aHuv3/7@ZmYWxMQA)

Comment: @scottinet Thanks! I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: @riley was going to say `use x` but that's 10 too... Nice answer. Thought `x` would get rid of `D`, but it's the same idea.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
(]1&(+$:)2**)10>#@~.@":
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQfaf4WIRaxMxoZkLhRVpFEW3aturq9t5dyoklQW/c6q5JRqw1TGudvyGrVFXHfj3Q/WkU4U0IPEl0sx8hCCE6BxbnxzDFmcBE8FLKDw)

### Explanation

```
(]1&(+$:)2**)10>#@~.@":  Input: integer n
                     ":  Format as string
                  ~.@    Unique
                #@       Length
             10>         Less than 10
           *             Multiply, gives n if previous was true, else 0
         2*              Multiply by 2
 ]                       Get the previous condition
  1&(   )                Execute this if true on 2n, else return 0
      $:                   Recurse
  1  +                     Add 1
```

Comment: Nice. I was stuck on collecting the results, didn't think about using that type of recursive function.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), <del>31</del> 28 bytes (27 chars)

*-3 bytes thanks to @Joshua*

```perl6
{($_,2×*...*.comb.Set>9)-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYKvwv1pDJV7H6PB0LT09PS295PzcJL3g1BI7S01dw9r/1lzFiSCFGkaa1v8B)

**Explanation:** Still the same construct to recursively generate lists. The first element is the given number (`$_`), each next element is 2 times the previous (`2×*` — we use ×, because, although 2 byte character, it's still 1 byte cheaper than `2 * *`), and we do this until the end condition of `*.comb.unique>9` is satisfied, i. e. when there is more than 9 unique characters in the number. (Technically, we break the string down to a list of characters with `.comb`, force it to a set with `.Set` (of course, Sets contain each element only once), and compare with 9, which forces the set into numerical context, which in turn gives its number of elements.)

Finally, we subtract 1 from this list. Again, the list is forced into numerical context, so what we return is 1 less than the length of that list.

Comment: You can use `.Set` instead of `.unique` to save 3 bytes.

Comment: @Joshua, good point! Thank you. I never thought of this.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6) + [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/), <s>84</s> <s>74</s> <s>73</s> 70 bytes

*Thanks [@ConorO'Brien](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/conor-obrien) for saving 10 bytes by suggesting [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/) instead of bignumber.js*
*Thanks to [@Rick Hitchcock](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42260/rick-hitchcock) for -1 byte*
*Thanks to [@Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy) for -3 bytes*

```js
f=n=>[..."4"+2**29].every(d=>RegExp(d).test(c=Big(n)))?0:1+f(c.mul(2))
```

Takes input as string; supports up to around 2<sup>69</sup> due to automatic scientific notation conversion occurring beyond that point.

### Test Snippet

```js
f=n=>[..."4"+2**29].every(d=>RegExp(d).test(c=Big(n)))?0:1+f(c.mul(2))

;[617283945, 2, 66833, 1234567890, 100, 42].forEach(t=>console.log(`f(${t}) = `+f(t)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/MikeMcl/big.js/c6fadd08/big.min.js"></script>
```

### Infinite range, <s>106</s> <s>88</s> <s>87</s> 84 bytes

By using the config option to effectively disable scientific notation when converting numbers to strings, we can have nearly infinite range.

```js
f=n=>[..."4"+2**29].every(d=>RegExp(d).test(c=Big(n)),Big.E_POS=1e9)?0:1+f(c.mul(2))

let num = `${Math.random()*1e6|0}`.repeat(100)
O.innerText=`f(\n${num}\n) = ${f(num)}`
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/MikeMcl/big.js/c6fadd08/big.min.js"></script>
<pre id=O style="width:100%;white-space:normal;overflow-wrap:break-word"></pre>
```

Comment: Maybe you could shorten the `BigNumber` bit by using [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/)?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien That will definitely help, especially because `new` is optional in that one. Will update, thanks!

Comment: Save one byte with `f=n=>[..."0123456789"].every(d=>RegExp(d).test(c=Big(n)))?0:1+f(c.mul(2))`.

Comment: We don't need to handle big integers so you could drop big.js if you wanted, bringing you down to 61 bytes. And you can save 3 bytes by replacing the string of digits with `"4"+2**29`: https://tio.run/##BcGxDkAwEADQb2GQO41LNBZDbX7AKgbhKkSu0jZSX1/vXeu7hs2fT2zE7ZyzNWKGYiaisiuVrmvdL8Qv@w@SGSY@xvRAQoocIghiVVkQJajavDkJ7ma63QEWOo2Yfw

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>12</s>, 11 bytes

```
QLn⁵
ḤÇÐ¿L’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//UUxu4oG1CuG4pMOHw5DCv0zigJn///80Mg)

> *Gotta go fast!*

Explanation:

```
        # Helper link, takes one argument 'z'
Q       # The unique digits of 'z'
 L      # Length
  n     # Does not equal
   ⁵    # 10
        #
        # Main link
  Ð¿    # While <condition> is true, run <body> and return all intermediate results
        # Condition:
 Ç      #   The helper link
        # Body:
Ḥ       #   Double the input
        # Now we have a list of all the 'z's that we passed to the helper link
    L   # Return it's length
     ’  # minus one
```

Comment: [Test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/QJ@9R41auhzuWHG4/POHQfp9HDTP/H25/1LTm/38zQ3MjC2NLE1MdBSMdBTMzC2NjHQVDI2MTUzNzC0sDINsASJgYAQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 43 bytes

```
f=:(,$:@+:@{.)`[@.(9<[:#@~.10&#.inv)
<:@#@f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvnqiQpK5ga6VgY60Xb6jg46ajUGulYKAAxP/TbK00dFSsHLStHKr1NBOiHfQ0LG2irZQd6vQMDdSU9TLzyjS5bKwclB3S/mtyKeklArF6uq2Vuk4SV2pyRr5CuoKJ0X8A)

Defines an anonymous function. Collects results quite suboptimally. Check out [miles's superior answer here!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142781/31957)

Comment: There’s no need for recursion, use `^:a:`: `1#@}.+:^:(10>#@~.@":)^:a:`

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 46 bytes

```hs
f n|all(`elem`show n)['0'..'9']=0|1<3=1+f(2*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hryYxJ0cjITUnNTehOCO/XCFPM1rdQF1PT91SPdbWoMbQxtjWUDtNw0grT/N/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmoKJ0X8A)

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, <s>115</s> <s>89</s> 82 bytes

-26 bytes by just using a string to represent the list of characters (duh, in retrospect), and changing from using recursion to `loop`, which allowed me to make a couple of optimizations.

-7 bytes by getting rid of the call to `bigint`. Apparently we only need to handle input that won't cause an overflow.

```clj
#(loop[n % c 0](if(empty?(remove(set(str n))"1234567890"))c(recur(* 2 n)(inc c))))
```

Pregolfed:

```clj
(defn pan [num]
  (loop [n num
         cnt 0]

    ; Remove all the characters from the stringified input
    ;  that are numeric. If the result is an empty list, all
    ;  the numbers were present.
    (if (empty? (remove (set (str n)) "1234567890"))
      cnt
      (recur (* 2 n) (inc cnt)))))
```

Comment: You can save 7 bytes by using `every?` instead of `empty? (remove …`: `#(loop[n % c 0](if(every?(set(str n))"1234567890")c(recur(* 2 n)(inc c)))))`

Comment: @bfontaine Oh, you're right! Thanks. I'll fix that later. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 44 bytes

```
until(\c->all(`elem`show(n*2^c))['0'..'9'])(+1)0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 85 bytes

```
^\d*
$&¶$&
D`.(?=.*¶)
\d{10}¶\d+|\d*¶

[5-9]
#$&
T`d`EE
T`_d#`d_`\d#
#
1
}`\d\b
$&@
@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYy7DcIwGAb7bw2HKAQR@RXHLhApiFiADkMM@iloKBAdZC0P4MWMq7vidO/H5/m65VXTHEO@empR1SlWNQ6ha/a7rk1xDU9fwZcUPW1@JUkROPdbdwEr4SlQmKaCmVigOXhiYBBYivl72Y0YczZikFY53UPCGKsUhFS6N4N1HIJzaPkH) Link includes test cases. Slightly optimised for run time. Explanation:

```
^\d*
$&¶$&
```

Duplicate the input number.

```
D`.(?=.*¶)
```

Deduplicate the digits in the first copy.

```
\d{10}¶\d+|\d*¶
```

If 10 digits remain, delete both numbers, otherwise just delete the first copy. Note that deleting both numbers causes the rest of the loop to no-op.

```
[5-9]
#$&
```

Place a `#` before large digits.

```
T`d`EE
```

Double each digit.

```
T`_d#`d_`\d#
```

Add in the carries.

```
#
1
```

Deal with a leading carry.

```
}`\d\b
$&@
```

Append an `@` and loop until all 10 digits are found.

```
@
```

Print the number of `@`s added.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>132</s> <s>110</s> <s>87</s> 74 bytes

```java
n->{int c=0;for(;(n+"").chars().distinct().count()!=10;n*=2)c++;return c;}
```

-57 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hY5NbsMgEEb3OcU0K6gV4r84jpB7g2aTZdUFxSQltQcLcKoq8tld7LbLyhJo@EZvhncVN7ExncJr/THKRjgHz0LjfQWg0St7FlLBcYpzAyRpDF4AKQ@tIdxwjoBQwYibp/uMVDE/G0s4wWi9pky@C@sIZbV2XqP04SlNj6E@VEnM8bFKqYwibpXvLYLkwzgt7/q3RktwXvhQbkbX0AYzcvJW4@XlFQT90Zp8oQ0GqD7nQGY5gNOX86plpvesCzO@QdIyZJIkaZbvin15iOkSWiT7tMwO@W6ZLMosW6SSePnPPP1Dttt/oV9mWA3jNw) (Note: test case for `2` is disabled because it should stop at 2<sup>68</sup>, but the size of `long` is limited to 2<sup>63</sup>-1.)

```java
n->          // Method with long parameter and integer return-type
  int c=0;   //  Count-integer, starting at 0
  for(;(n+"").chars().distinct().count()!=10;
             //  Loop (1) as long as the unique amount of digits in the number are not 10
    n*=2)    //    After every iteration: multiply the input by 2
   c++;      //   Increase the count by 1
             //  End of loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
  return c;  //  Return the counter
}            // End of method
```

---

Old **132 bytes** answer using a `String` input and regex:

```java
n->f(n,0)int f(String n,int c){String t="";for(int i=0;i<10;t+="(?=.*"+i+++")");return n.matches(t+".*")?c:f(new Long(n)*2+"",c+1);}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jZDLbsIwFET3@Yorr2wMefJsmvIDLRuWVRfGOGBK7Ci5oUIo3546lLKrimTLmtHx@I4P4iRGtlTmsP3s5FHUNbwJbS4egDaoqlxIBateXg2QdI2VNjswLHVm67ZbKzCQQWdGLzk1w5B5qcODAFYWoRQVgs0B9wo2Z1QjaRuDXh@W38OG12x2uWnMCElzW9He1lmY6ucoTJFnhC4zf0C45pwTRlhaKWwqA8YvBMq9qily4gC2lE9uFPUFr9bsqGGDmBMylDxiadsBlM3mqCXUKNAdJ6u3ULjat3neP0Cwn879Z0DhyvVZvaDX3gDrc42q8G2Dfunu4NHQwje@pCSKk/FkOpsvQsL@hafRLJ4ni/HkEXY6T5IHuCh85OVxfIeC4G/sl2q9tvsG) (Note: test case for `2` is disabled because it causes a StackOverflowException due to slightly too much recursion.)

The total regex to check if the String contains all 9 digits becomes `^(?=.*0)(?=.*1)(?=.*2)(?=.*3)(?=.*4)(?=.*5)(?=.*6)(?=.*7)(?=.*8)(?=.*9).*$`, which uses a positive look-ahead for the entire String.

Comment: [111 bytes](https://tio.run/##hY9Pb4JAEMXvfoqJp90iyD8Rg3jrsV48Eg7bddG1MBBYrA3ls9MF22NDMpPJe/lN5s2N3ZlZVgJv54@B56xp4I1J7BYAEpWoM8YFHEc5GcBJXuIFkEba6nXrOgJCDAOah25CYnv1SNK4s/soK2sSRY/ETrXJDWOFL7FLO4LGckktfmV1Q6ilqVfGr0SahxH9jp39Xgs/pDSSGZnWY8d2PVoL1dYIPOr7YUxQte@55NAopvS4l/IMhY5PTqqWeElSYPSZfXwKCh0TxeckyPQBwOmrUaKwylZZld5ROZLCQosTx/X8TbANdzadQwNn64bezt/Mk0HoebOUY8/f9N0/ZL3@F/pl@kU//AA) (yup, the byte count is a "uni-digital" ;-)

Comment: Note that 2 will never work because we expect `2^68` as first pandigital number, but longs in Java are limited to `2^63-1`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks! And 1 more byte saved by putting the ints inside the loop.

Comment: Yeah, kind of forgot that. I liked my "uni-digital", though ^^

Comment: [87 bytes](https://tio.run/##hY7PboMwDIfvfQqvp2SUlH@lVCl9g/XS47RDCGlHBwaF0GnqeHYWWHeckGxZP@uz/F3FTbh1o/CafwyyFG0LL6LA@wKgQKP0WUgFxzFOC5CkrPECSLld9bZtHQEhhQHdw31CUo@fa004QWe5pEy@C90SyrTKO6mItyJilVH3IL5Tf78nmRsllD6lvheEXDoOxec04FqZTiNI3g/jp6bLykJCa4Sx41YXOVRWk5yMLvDy@gaC/jqO8lBZHVSfUyCTKcDpqzWqYnVnWGNvTImkYsgk8YMw2sTbZOfROTT2t0ES7qLNPBknYThL@d78zyj4Q9brf6EH0y/64Qc). Thanks `reduce` \o/

Comment: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##hY5NbsMgEEb3OcU0K6gV4r84jpB7g2aTZdUFxSQltQcLcKoq8tld7LbLyhJo@EZvhncVN7ExncJr/THKRjgHz0LjfQWg0St7FlLBcYpzAyRpDF4AKQ@tIdxwjoBQwYibp/uMVDE/G0s4wWi9pky@C@sIZbV2XqP04SlNj6E@VEnMZRRRfKxSbpXvLYLkwzgt7/q3RktwXvhQbkbX0AYzcvJW4@XlFQT90Zp8oQ0GqD7nQGY5gNOX86plpvesCzO@QdIyZJIkaZbvin15iOkSWiT7tMwO@W6ZLMosW6SSePnPPP1Dttt/oV9mWA3jNw). Stopping here ;-)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah nice, of course. `(n+"").chars().distinct().count()!=10` if the number contains all ten digits. Smart, smart.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I know you obliterated your old method, but just want to point out that you can use the following regex to match all 10 digits: `(?:.*?(\d)(?!.*\1)){10}`

Comment: @jaytea Ah nice, that's 81 bytes, which isn't too bad either: `n->{int c=0;for(;!(n+"").matches("(?:.*?(\\d)(?!.*\\1)){10}");n*=2)c++;return c;}`. Feel free to post it as an alternative answer if you want.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 19 + 2 = 21 bytes

```apl
0∘{∧/⎕D∊⍕⍵:⍺⋄⍺+1∇2×⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HfVLegR20TDI0szLmAnIAAIMfYhCsNSFU/6liuDxRzedTR9ah36qPerVaPenc96m4BktqGjzrajQ5PBwrW/v9voJCmYGZobmRhbGliygXiGYFJMzMLY2Mwy9DI2MTUzNzC0gDCNYDQJkYA)

This is a dyadic `Dfn` (**d**irect **f**unctio**n**), taking 0 as its left argument and the integer as the right. Since the input is supposed to be only the integer, I added 2 bytes for the argument `0∘` to the byte count.

`f←` is not included in the byte count, since it's not *necessary*. It just makes it easier to build the test cases.

#### How it works:

**The headers:**
I removed those from the byte count after some chatting in the APL room, since the function does what it's supposed to do and the results are only incorrect because of the default settings of APL's REPL.

`⎕FR←1287` Sets the **F**loat **R**epresentation to 128-bit decimal (7 is the code for decimal in APL's REPL).
`⎕PP←34` Sets the **P**rint **P**recision to 34 digits.
Both of these are needed, since APL's default representation for big numbers transforms them to scientific notation (e.g. 3.14159265359E15) which messes up the code big time.

```apl
0∘{∧/⎕D∊⍕⍵:⍺⋄⍺+1∇2×⍵} ⍝ Dyadic Dfn
0∘                     ⍝ Fixes 0 as the left argument  
          :            ⍝ If
     ⎕D                ⍝ String representation of all digits [0, 9]
       ∊               ⍝ "is in"
        ⍕⍵             ⍝ String representation of the input
   ∧/                  ⍝ AND-reduction. Yields 1 (true) iff all digits are in the right argument.
           ⍺           ⍝ return the left argument
            ⋄          ⍝ Else
                 2×⍵   ⍝ Double the right arg
             ⍺+1       ⍝ increment the left arg
                ∇      ⍝ Recursively call this function with the new arguments.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
←Vö>9Lud¡D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUUAuv9odXNr/yBtyK9z4oKBcsK2/@KGkFbDtj45THVkwqFE////NjE3MjgzOTQ1CjIKNjY4MzMKMTIzNDU2Nzg5MAoxMDAKNDI)

#### Explanation

```
        ¡D    Repeatedly double the input, collecting results in a list
 V            Return the first index where the following is true
     L          The length of
       d        the digits
      u         with duplicates removed
  ö>9           is greater than 9
←             Decrement (as Husk uses 1-indexing)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>59</s> <s>48</s> <s>47</s> <s>46</s> 38 bytes

*-9 bytes thanks to Jenny_mathy.*

```
If[!FreeQ[DigitCount@#,0],#0[2#]+1,0]&
```

[Try it online using Mathics!](https://tio.run/##JYw9C8JAEET7/IqVgE22uI/kcgEDghIQLLRerhC5JFeYQLJW4m8/T51ieDyYedx4DPc19m089bTpFu@vdAxD4MP8nHifo3CYC1K5K2TibWS/8gotvIysldVNWSEoBGOs1ghS6bIytW1EYpGqVO8s6@aFQtpIhAC7Fs5@Gnik35VLrigQLkuYmPq/JArum/gB)

Comment: 46 bytes:  If[Tr[1^Union@IntegerDigits@#]<10,#0[2#]+1,0]&

Comment: Mathematica allows for anonymous recursive functions. :o Thanks!

Comment: 38 bytes:   If[!FreeQ[DigitCount@#,0],#0[2#]+1,0]&

Comment: Oh, thanks! BTW, ` ` can be used for code but leading whitespace is not allowed. `a` will work but ` a` won't.

Comment: sure!BTW you can use this footer in TIO  `Print/@f/@{617283945,2,66833,1234567890,100,42}`

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>70</s> 69 bytes

```powershell
for($n=[bigint]$args[0];([char[]]"$n"|group).count-le9;$n*=2){$i++}$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAv8QeMikiuoT4EvFgYSbIGmvSoXr7NnPm21M5fErMe6YWUJs1hoiXBUehmNGq1myHI2NtA9i8gXI9xbDlilef/KIAOz2JB6KUH0Rmnqcf)

*(Nearly twice as long as the Python answer :-\ )*

Takes input `$args[0]`, casts it as a `[bigint]`, saves it to `$n`. Enters a `for` loop. Each iteration we check against whether the `$n`umber converted to a string then to a `char`-array, when `Group-Object`'d together, has a `.count` `-l`ess than or `e`qual to `9`. Meaning, the only way that it equals 10 is if at least one digit of every number `1234567890` is present. If yes, we exit the loop. If not, we `$n*=2` and continue. Each iteration inside the loop, we're simply incrementing `$i`. When we exit the loop, we simply output `$i`.

Note that for input like `1234567890` where every digit is already accounted for, this will output nothing, which is a falsey value in PowerShell, and equivalent to `0` when cast as an `[int]`. If that's not OK, we can simply put a `+` in front of the output `$i` to explicitly cast it as an integer.

*Saved a byte thanks to Roland Heath.*

Comment: Could you use le9 instead of ne10? I'm not familiar with powershell, but that might save a byte.

Comment: @RolandHeath Indeed; good call. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 74 bytes

```r
function(x){while(!all(0:9%in%el(strsplit(c(x,""),"")))){F=F+1;x=2*x};F*1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxNCoMwGET3PUUrCF9sF@bHaCrZeg9rDQbSWJKUpohnT9WB4c3bjEtGP1zvfvAawzQ/PTqps0zqY4egZwsRLd9JmxEuvTFQ3kWubT4a8MH5t9EBBoi3LEN7tyyd7K64jZIUcW27Aq9JAcc1aahg1fYNnDeU7gMTyipeN6I8rDzACEp/) Note that R will give the wrong answer to `f(2)` due to limitations of how the language stores large integers.

Explanation: For the test of pandigitality, the input is coerced to a character vector by joining with an empty string and then split into individual digits. We then check whether all of 0:9 are present in the resulting vector; if not, we increment the counter, double the input and repeat.

The counter uses F which initialises as FALSE. To make sure it is coerced to numeric, we multiply by one before returning.

Comment: using `c(x,"")` is a neat trick for `el(strsplit(...))`

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <del>46</del> <del>45</del> <del>39</del> 38 bytes

```
def f n;n.digits.uniq[9]?0:1+f(n*2)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/PyU1TSFNIc86Ty8lMz2zpFivNC@zMNoy1t7AylA7TSNPy0gzNS/lf0FpSbFGmoaZobmRhbGliammJhdUyAjBNDOzMDZGcA2NjE1MzcwtLA2QxAyQOCZAvf8B)

Updates:

1. -1 by using `def f n;` instead of `def f(n);`.
2. -6 by using `…[9]` instead of `….size==10`
3. -1 by removing a semicolon

Answer (score 1):

## [q/kdb+](http://kx.com/download), 33 bytes

**Solution:**

```
(#)1_{x*2 1 min!:[10]in 10 vs x}\
```

**Examples:**

```
q)(#)1_{x*2 1 min!:[10]in 10 vs x}\[100]
51
q)(#)1_{x*2 1 min!:[10]in 10 vs x}\[1234567890]
0
q)(#)1_{x*2 1 min!:[10]in 10 vs x}\[42]
55
```

**Explanation:**

All the bytes are in the equality, might be able to golf this one down a little further. Utilises q's `scan` adverb:

```
count 1_{x*2 1 min til[10] in 10 vs x}\ / ungolfed solution
        {                            }\ / scan over this lambda until it yields same result
                              10 vs x   / convert to base 10
                           in           / left list in right list, returns boolean list
                   til[10]              / range 0..9
               min                      / return the minimum of the list, 0 or 1
           2 1                          / list (2;1) indexed into with 0 or 1
         x*                             / return x multiplied by either 2 or 1
      1_                                / 1 drop, drop one element from front of list
count                                   / count the length of the list
```

**Notes:**

If we drop to the `k` prompt then we can have a 25 byte solution. Converts the number to a list of characters:

```
q)\
  #1_{x*2 1@&/($!10)in$$x}\[100]
51
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
f>l{`.<QT9Z
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%3El%7B%60.%3CQT9Z&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=617283945%0A2%0A66833%0A1234567890%0A100%0A42&debug=0).

First natural number `T` where `input << T` meets the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 52 + 1 (-p) = 53 bytes

```perl
$/=10;for$i(0..9){$/-=/$i/}$_*=2;++$\;$/&&redo}{$\--
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAzyxSyboqdQjxCf1A6JKBECnWTfx620yJ9VqYgbzR7swV0qCVWscGhJ4gUYd98tZJCcEBCVHjkXuDgMg82y@XN@X7YdwWpY1mLD8)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 43 + 1 bytes

```
for$x(0..9){$_*=2,++$\,redo LINE if!/$x/}}{
```

Using the `-p` flag. This builds on the solution provided by Xcali above.

Answer (score 0):

## **Swift 4**, 111 bytes

```
func p(_ x:Int,_ c:Int=0)->Int{if !(String(Set(String(x)).sorted())=="0123456789"){return p(x*2,c+1)};return c}
```

Note: Won't work for x = 2, because of overflow.

Explanation - Input x is first typecasted to string. Then Set() removes the repeating characters. Then it is sorted to match the result. If it doesn't match, x is doubles and counter is incremented.

Comment: it doesn't wok because the var is 64 bits. There a lot of other answers with same problem.

Comment: @FunkyComputerMan [It is common practice to restrict challenges to cases where input, output and/or intermediate values of the algorithm of choice fit into the language's native number type. At least for input and output, this is generally assumed even if not stated in the challenge specification.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8245/66252)

Comment: If you think that this should be allowed bring it up with the OP.  It may be common practice but the OP has not specifically allowed it and the testcases seem to suggest you need to support 2.

Comment: @FunkyComputerMan actually, I did allow answers that can't handle numbers outside the bounds of the language, but Shaggy seems to have deleted the comment asking about that. This answer is fine.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/), 15 bytes

```
LÆ*2pXÃbì_â Ê¥A
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=TMYqMnBYw2LsX+IgyqVB&input=NDI=)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of integer `U`.

```
LÆ    Ã
```

Create an array of integers from `0` to `99` and pass each through a function  where `X` is the current element.

```
*2pX
```

`U` multiplied by 2 raised to the power of `X`.

```
b
```

Get the index of the first element thay returns true when passed through the following function.

```
ì_â
```

Split to an array of digits and remove the duplicates.

```
Ê¥A
```

Get the length of the array and check for equality with `10`.

---

### Alternative, 15 bytes

```
@*2pX)ìâ sÊ¥A}a
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=QCoycFgp7OIgc8qlQX1h&input=NDI=)

---

#### Explanation

Implicit input of integer `U`.

```
@            }a
```

Starting with `0`, return the first number that returns true when passed through the following function, with `X` being the current number.

```
*2pX)
```

As above, multiply `U` by 2 to the power of `X`.

```
ìâ
```

Split to an array of digits, remove duplicates and rejoin to an integer.

```
sÊ
```

Convert to a string, get the length and convert back to an integer.

```
¥A
```

Check for equality with `10`.

Answer (score 0):

## GNU dc, 61 bytes

Input is copied from top of stack (which must be otherwise empty); output is pushed to top of stack.

```
[I~1r:ad0<s]ss[d1+r;a1=p]sp[d2*lfx]sh[0Sadlsxlpx11!=h]dsfxz1-
```

### Explanation

We use the array variable `a`, storing a 1 in `a[d]` if digit `d` is present, otherwise falling back to 0 there.  We use the GNU extension `~` to obtain quotient and remainder in a single command.

```
# populate a[0-9] from the digits
[I~1r:ad0<s]ss

# check pandigit
# return 1 more than lowest unset element of a[]
# start with stack=0
[d1+r;a1=p]sp

# Test for pandigit; double and repeat if needed
[dd+lfx]sh
[0Sadlsxlpx11!=h]dsfx

# We left one value on the stack for each doubling, plus the original
z1-
```

As a bonus, this will work in arbitrary number bases (not only decimal): simply set the input radix as required (the constant `11` in the definition of `f` will be read using that number base, so is automatically correct).

### Test

```sh
for i in 617283945 2 66833 1234567890 100 42
do
    printf '%s => ' $i
    dc -e $i \
       -e '[I~1r:ad0<s]ss[d1+r;a1=p]sp[dd+lfx]sh[0Sadlsxlpx11!=h]dsfxz1-' \
       -e p
done
```

```
617283945 => 1
2 => 67
66833 => 44
1234567890 => 0
100 => 51
42 => 55
```

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 57 bytes

```
arg n
do b=0 while verify(0123456789,n)>0
  n=n*2
  end
say b
```